# python tkinter, by button click take value for the key in dictionary & use for calculations

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, menu

i am trying to develop a program to select the drinks by clicking the buttons and then enter quantity, which should give me the total cost for the drinks.
the drinks and price are entered as dictionary in the program.

## my dictonary list

```
`my_dict={"COFFEE":40, "LATTE":50, "TEA":15, "CUPPUCINO":15}`
```

## Variables

```
`E_QTY=StringVar()
t=StringVar()
E_QTY.set("")
E_TOT=StringVar()
E_TOT.set("")`
```

## Clicking the button

```
`def press():
    l1.config(text="TEA")
def press1():
    l1.config(text="COFFEE")
def press2():
    l1.config(text="LATTE")
def press3():
    l1.config(text="CUPPUCINO")`
```

## Clicking the button for calculating the total

```
`def press8():
    t=(my_dict.get(l1))
    x=t*(E_QTY)
    E_TOT=x`

`Teabutton=Button(f1, text="TEA",font="Arial 12", width=8, height=1, 
          command=press).pack(side=LEFT)
Coffeebutton=Button(f1, text="COFFEE",font="Arial 12", width=8, 
          height=1,command=press1).pack(side=LEFT)
lattebutton=Button(f1, text="LATTE",font="Arial 12", width=8, 
          height=1, command=press2).pack(side=LEFT)
cuppubutton=Button(f1, text="CUPPUCINO",font="Arial 12",width=8, 
          height=1, command=press3).pack(side=LEFT)`


 `Chlabel = Label(f4, text="Your Choice is :",font="Arial 12", fg="Blue")
 Chlabel.pack()
 l1 = Label(f5, text=" ",font="Arial 12", fg="Blue")
  l1.pack()# the drinks coming in this label should be used as key to take value`
 
  `txtQty = Entry(f6,font= 
   ('arial',10),bd=5,width=8,justify=LEFT,textvariable=E_QTY)
   txtQty.pack(side=TOP)
    Calcbutton=Button(f6, text="CALCULATE",font="Arial 12", 
    fg="Blue",width=8, height=1,command=press8).pack(side=TOP)
    txtTot = Label(f6,font= 
    ('arial',10,'bold'),bd=5,width=8,justify=LEFT,textvariable=t)
     txtTot.pack(side=TOP)`
```

Comment: so what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: if i press the TEA button for example it shows up in the CHLABEL area, i want that "TEA" to be used as key to bring the value in the dictionary my_dict, which should be 15,

Comment: To get the value of a label, you can use `Label["text"]`. In your case it will be `t=(my_dict.get(l1["text"]))`.

Comment: my_dict={"Coffee":40, "Juice":50, "Tea":15}

    inputString1 = input('Enter choice Tea or Coffee or Juice:')
    print('Your choice is:', inputString1)

    inputString2 = input('Enter Qty of choice:')
    print('Qty of your choice is:', inputString2)


    t=(my_dict.get(inputString1))
    x=t*int(inputString2)
    print('Price for your choice is :', t)

    print('Please pay cost :', x)                                                                               dis my prog, which worked good when checked n python shell, now i want the same program in GUI with tkinter.